# ZF2 Skeleton Application out of memory error

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx, zend-framework2, vagrant

Okay, so, I've got Vagrant set up, running Ubuntu 14.04, with Nginx (latest available), and PHP 5.6.

Other sites on the VM work fine, but are pretty minimalist and don't use a framework, but do run PHP.

My issue is that I have just pulled the ZF2 skeleton application, and when attempting to access the configured vhost for it, I either get a `502 Bad Gateway` error, or a PHP error

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
  (tried to allocate 1931504738 bytes) in 
  /var/www/backbone-blog/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/
    Zend/Validator/Hostname.php on line 0
```

I'm really confused as to why I can get either one of these two errors, and am even more confused as to how to go about fixing them. I've made no changes to the skeleton app yet at all, so it's a fresh copy.

Any help would be really appreciated, and thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

I've tried the suggestions listed here, with the exception of the php5-fpm.sock suggestion, as that file doesn't exist where they suggested: http://laravel.io/forum/05-14-2014-502-bad-gateway-in-vagrant-permission-denied.

Also, it seems pretty consistent that I get a 502 error followed by the out of memory error, then repeat.

Comment: I've seen this happen consistently and reproducible with some PHP-level redirect loops -- weird though, the error should be about reaching the max level of function nesting not memory consumption.

Comment: Yeah, it's just weird how it either gives a bad gateway or a PHP error. I mean, surely that's not possible? Nginx either doesn't hand the request over to PHP properly or it does, right? How on earth can it flip-flop between the two? And even more bizarrely; why does the fresh install of ZF2 Skeleton throw memory errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so, whilst this isn't a real fix as such, it's got me up and running.

I essentially stripped out everything I absolutely didn't need in my puppet config file, and most importantly **downgraded PHP to 5.5, despite puppet giving you 5.6 by default on Ubuntu 14.04**

After running yet another

```
vagrant destroy
```

Followed by

```
Vagrant up
```

Everything seems to work okay. There's obviously some issue here, but if you're really stuck, try this. 5.6 is pretty brand-spanking new anyway - I certainly don't need it for what I'm doing, and I'm a developer not a sysadmin, so these sort of errors just cost me hours and hours of time to no end.

Hopefully this at least gets someone off the ground!